# How to do $-(1100.1)_2 - (1.010)_2$ using 1's complement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic, binary

Convert $A = (12.5)_{10}$ and $B= (1.45)_{16}$ into binary format employing 6 bits for the integer part and 3 for the fractional part, including the sign bit. Perform $- A - B$  using 1's complement

First I converted $A$ and $B$ into binary. $A =1100.1$ and $B = 1.010$ .
Then I made sure to have 6 bits including a sign bit and 3 bits in the fractional part.
$A = 001100.100$ and $B = 000001.010$ where the first bit is 0 because  $A$ and $B$ are positive.
After I took the 1's complement of A and B which gives me: $[A]_1 = 110011.011$ and $[B]_1 = 111110.101$ then I added  $[a] + [b] = 110010.000$ with a carry of $1$. after I added $1$ to the result which gives me $110011.000$. after that, since the sign bit is 1, it means I need to take the complement of my answer which is $- 001100.111$ which is $-12.875$ which is not a good answer. the good answer should be $-13.75$. I don't understand where I went wrong. I know that if I didn't add the carry then after taking the complement I would've had a good answer but I was told to always add the carry and if your answer should be negative take the complement and a negative sign. Why would this case be different? I don't want to memorize the steps, I want to understand.

Comment: For $A=12.5$, $12 = (1100)_2$ is the integer part, but may I ask how did you convert the fractional part using 3 bits, since $2^3=8$?

Comment: @James $ (0.5)_{10} = (.1)_2$. then to have 3 bits in the fractional part I just added 2 zeros at the end which doesn't change anything. so $(0.5)_{10} = (.100)_2$

Comment: Thank you, I have only seen 1's and 2's complement in integer settings. How would we convert, say, 12.67 using this method?

Comment: you need to multiply 0.67 * 2  then take the integer part then multiply the decimal part by 2  and you do this 3 times to have 3 bits.

Comment: I think you just missed a single step, that is since the carry is 1, we need to add 1 to the answer *to the smallest decimal place* before inverting back the one's complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A = 001100.100$$
$$B = 000001.010$$

Evaluate $(-A) + (-B)$:

$$ -A = 110011.011$$
$$ -B = 111110.101$$
Hence,
$$(-A) + (-B) $$
$$= (carry=1)110010.000 $$
$$=110010.000+\color{red}{000000.001}$$
$$=110010.001$$
$$= - (001101.110)$$
$$= - 13.75$$

Comment: Ohh I added the carry but I did 110010.000 + 000001 = 110011.000. I did not know we needed to add the carry to the decimal point. How so? is this how I always proceed or you just did it and u saw that it worked? However thank you for your response

Comment: @user20194358 I reasoned if we remove the decimal point (by multiplying everything by $2^3$), the usual rule would apply $110010000 + 000000001 = 110010001$, and then if we reinsert the decimal point at the third digit (divide everything by $2^3$) then we would get $110010.001$, so the same rule should apply to add the 1 to the smallest fractional decimal digit, instead of the integer part.